# Solving for big $G$ in a Cavendish's torsion balance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

I'm having trouble with determining gravity in a Cavendish experiment (torsion balance):

[image: Cavendisk experiment]

I don't really get one question in my textbook regarding this torsion balance. The question asked if **one** of the **smaller** masses has its mass doubled, and the mass of the rest of the four masses (the other smaller mass and the two bigger masses) stay the same, what is $G$ of the system?

Well, my answer is double the original $G$, because $F_g = \frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$, and $m_1$ is doubled. However, my friend says that its $1.5G$, because in the equation for $F_g$ above, $m_1$ is the **sum** of the two smaller masses, which means that $0.5m_1 + 0.5m_1\cdot 2$, which is $1.5m_1$. Hence the new $G$ is $1.5$ times the original $G$.

I don't really comprehend his idea, because when we measure $r$ (as in distance between the centers), we use one small mass and one big mass (as shown at the bottom of website's diagram). For his idea to work, we have to set $r=0$ because both the centers of the masses are at the very center of the system.

I'm very confused. I don't only want to know who's correct but also at least some details of why one of us is correct.

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does your textbook say about G?

Comment: I am not keen on the asymmetry which had been introduced.  Where is the new axis of rotation?

Comment: @Farcher: How is the asymmetry of a poorly put together torsion balance going to change a fundamental constant of the universe? :-) Oops... I think I just gave it away, didn't I? :-)